# How do I re-use the query formed by bolean query when executing the same search next time in Lucene.Net

Tags: lucene.net

I am using lucene.Net for searching in my application.
I have to search in two fields so I am adding two term queries in a boolean query and the resulted boolean query is 
+(location:a* +(id:19))

I am using pagination to display results to the user. When I want to get next n records in my result set I am again exeuting the same search.

When executing search for the next time I dont want to prepare the query and I want o use the same query "+(location:a* +(id:19))" as is.

How do I use it, which query should I use..because al most all types query requires field name. But I have the query which is parsed and want to use as is.

Please let me know if some body has any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the [Queryparser.Parse()](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.1/Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser.Parse.html) method to parse the query string and get a Query object.
2. Store the Query object for the next round.
3. Use one of the [Searcher.Search()](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.1/Lucene.Net.Search.Searcher.Search_overloads.html) methods with the stored Query.